# Getting "Unable to complete authentication for user due to looping logins" while making an api call through postman to azure

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, postman

I am trying to fetch ticket using azure api, but it's showing "Unable to complete authentication for user due to looping logins" while making an api call, i have passed proper Authorization header and provided correct personal access token in base64 encoded.(see fig)

I am using `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=1.0` for making an api call.
link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

am i missing something? Looking for suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Postman, to execute RESI API using PAT (Personal Access Token) as the authentication, you should set on **Authorization** tab, instead of directly on the **Headers** tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The personal access token may not have enough scope. Try changing the scope of token

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).